# How to output image via php from another domain

Tags: php, image

Image tag inside email message:

```
<img src="http://www.mydomain.com/image.php?lastest=1">
```

Part of image.php script:

```
case 'image/gif': header('Content-type: image/gif');$img=@imagecreatefromgif($image['src']);if($img) {imagegif($img);imagedestroy($img);}
break;
```

But how i can do the same with this image?

```
http://www.anotherdomain.com/image.gif
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .htaccess and redirecting the request, with something like:

```
RewriteRule image.gif$ /image.php?lastest=1 [l]
```

Comment: Yea i was thinking about redirect as well. I'll check if it's working.